# How do I rotate a 2D catenary in 3D space?

Tags: calculus, geometry, mathematical-modeling, hyperbolic-functions, data-analysis

I have data points of a catenary curve in 3D space (x,y,z co-ordinates). I am able to fit this data in 2D space properly with normal catenary equation y = a*cosh(x/a). However, on 3D space the catenary is not matching as the 3rd axis is not exactly on a plane and it is kind of rotated.

Can anyone suggest me how to rotate a 2D catenary in 3D space (P.S - I have already tried elementary rotation along all the planes)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @vbalaji Can you please be clearer about what exactly you're trying to do? It is possible to define a catenary in 2D space with 1 equation because a catenary is a $(2 - 1) = 1$-dimensional curve. However, using a single equation in 3-dimensional space would define a plane rather than a curve. Are you looking for a set of equations to define this curve in 3-D space? Are you looking for a [parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization_(geometry)) of this curve?

Comment: @vbalaji Since you're working with "data points", perhaps you could frame this as an algorithm/program that you're after. If the data-points are the input to your program, then what exactly is the desired output?